# align many div tags with css

Tags: html, css

I want to align more than five div tag on same line. Below is my css:

```
<style>
#yes { float: left; width: 18%; margin:1px; }
</style>
```

HTML example:

```
echo '<div id="yes">'.'<b>'.'Job Title: '.'</b></div>'.'<br />';
```

Here what I got: 
    https://www.dropbox.com/s/823gos5qoa0vw6u/1.jpg

Why does it happen? I'm trying to adjust `width` and `margin` but it still doesn't align on the same line.

Comment: Why are you echoing a break line if you want them to all be on the same line?

Comment: oh snap, never mind. stupid error! thank you

Comment: try to delete <br /> use **echo '<div id="yes">'.'<b>'.'Job Title: '.'</b></div>';**

Comment: What's with the superfluous concatenation in your PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of your line break `<br/>`
Remove this and you should see your problem resolved

Answer (score 2):

Add `position: absolute;` to your CSS.